# Conversion failed date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

the output is a combination from two column and need to convert into date. Data source is numeric. The code works well for the first 100,000 and and error occur after 409,560. Error as "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

```
SELECT

CASE WHEN LEN(OR6) = 6 THEN 
        CAST(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ORT),1,4),SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(10),OR6),3,2),SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(10),OR6),1,2))AS DATE) 
    WHEN LEN(OR6) = 5 THEN 
        CAST(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ORT),1,4),SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(10),OR6),2,2),'0',SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(10),OR6),1,1))AS DATE) 
    ELSE NULL 
END AS ORI_MAT_DT ,DATE1 = OR6 ,DATE2 = ORT
FROM DATETABLE
```

This is the original source database:

```
ROW       OR6      ORT
409,559  10611  2011152
409,560  50618  2018156
409,561  10615  2015152
409,562  50618  2018156
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
ORI_MAT_DT  DATE1   DATE2 
2001-08-15  150801  2001227
```

Comment: Can't you see what the value for `ORG6` is when it fails, I mean if you know it happens at row 409560? I know see there are 3 columns involved in converting to a date and you print a 4th but still are those values not known?

Comment: Far as I know `LEN` doesn't exist in mysql, are you sure you're not using sql server?

Comment: It looks like the error also is Sql Server, anyway maybe add some sample data to the question

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I already checked row 409561 & 409562 where the value is similar as previous data. The data type is numeric. Is it I need to change my code or is there any limit for data convert ? I already added the source on top. Thanks

Comment: @HoneyBadger I am sorry, my mistake.

Comment: What's the exact data type of `OR6` and `ORT`?  Why does your expected result not match the source data?

Comment: @ZoharPeled the expected result just an example and I randomly pick. The exact data type for OR6 & ORT is numeric. Sorry for the misinformation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little math to get the values you want from the numeric values in `OR6` and `ORT`, and then use [`DateFromParts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to construct the date:

Source data:

```
DECLARE @Date1 numeric(10,2) = 150801,
        @Date2 numeric(10,2) = 2001227
```

Query:

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(
        @Date2 / 1000, -- Get the year
       (@Date1 % 10000 - @Date1 % 100) / 100, -- Get the month
        @Date1 / 10000 -- Get the day
       ) As Date
```

Result:

```
Date
2001-08-15
```

The `DateFromParts` functions takes `int` values representing the year, month, and day and construct a `Date` object. Since it takes `int`, SQL Server will implicitly convert the numeric values you get from the calculations to `int` by truncating the decimal part.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, i will try it now.